# Cosa significa "far saltare" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> La fortuna non cessava d’accompagnare i Rabino: le annate senza essere sante erano buone, e sia le bestie che la famiglia non si risentivano mai un briciolo di male; in quanto al padrone, solo io posso dire la roba che gli **ha fatto saltare** Tobia. La mia paga dunque non pericolava, ma questo non mi bastava già piú; ormai a Tobia io gli rendevo bene e valevo qualcosa di piú dei sette marenghi l’anno del patto con mio padre.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato della frase "solo io posso dire la roba che gli ha fatto saltare Tobia"? Le diverse accezioni per "far saltare" che ho trovato nei dizionari non sembrano avere senso nel contesto di questo brano.

Comment: Qui far saltare mi pare possa essere intesto come rubare.

Comment: È possibile. Un'altra interpretazione è che questo Tobia abbia comunque "perso" della roba del padrone ovvero abbia fatto perdere ricchezza a quest'ultimo (per trascuratezza o incompetenza) anche senza rubare.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Tuttavia il brano dà a intendere che Tobia Rabino si era in certo modo arricchito facendo questo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00444.jpg) ho trovato questa accezione dell'espressione  "far saltare" che si addice al contesto del brano riportato nella domanda:

> – Svanire, andare dilapidato (un patrimonio). 
>       *Goldoni*, III-36: Le due pezze di panno le ho vendute a tredici  lire  il  braccio  ed  ho  tirato  il  denaro,  ma non  voglio ch'egli  lo  sappia; non glieli  voglio dar tutti, perché,  se li ha nelle  mani, li farà saltare in un giorno. *Tommaseo*,  CIX-I-172:  Il  duca,  non  più  ministro  e  giocatore  e  prodigo  e matto, farà saltare que' milioni del conte di Pavia!

Quindi, come in questi esempi, questo personaggio, Tobia, aveva fatto venire a meno la ricchezza del padrone.

Comment: Complimenti al downvotatore a raffica: ha trovato un modo divertente per passare le giornate di quarantena, a quanto pare.